# Grails maven deploy not picking up distributionManagement settings

Tags: maven, grails, artifactory

I have a Grails 2.2.3 project that I'm trying to do a maven deploy from to artifactory.

I have a pom.xml file in the root of the project that contains:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>libs-release-local</name>
        <url>http://SERVER_NAME:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>libs-snapshot-local</name>
        <url>http://SERVER_NAME:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

However, when I do a: grails maven-deploy I get the following error:

```
| Skipping POM generation because 'pom.xml' exists in the root of the project...
| Error Error deploying artifact: Error deploying artifact 'GROUP:ARTIFACT:grails-app': Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file: http://SERVER_NAME:8081/artifactory/remote-repos/GROUPID/ARTIFACT/1.0.1/ARTIFACT-1.0.1.grails-app. Return code is: 405
| Error Have you specified a configured repository to deploy to (--repository argument) or specified distributionManagement in your POM?
| Error org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

for starters remote-repos is different to the repo in the distributionManagement section of the pom. Why is that section being ignored?